# Wait and accept user input without using ACCEPT in COBOL

Tags: cobol

In COBOL, how to listen and accept user input without using `ACCEPT`? The system administrator does not allow using `ACCEPT`.

Comment: What OS and what COBOL?

Comment: Also, knowing why the System Administrator does not allow you to use ACCEPT would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

OPEN a channel to SYSIN, and use READ. As Bill mentioned, this will likely be compiler dependent.  The SYSIN may be KEYBOARD or other mnemonic.